# Where is gsl_cdf_beta_Pinv() in PyGSL?

Tags: python, gsl, pygsl

I'm trying to use the distribution functions in a Python program (the random functions I've got figured out; I'm looking specifically for gsl_cdf_beta_Pinv()) and I can't find it.  Can someone tell me how I can use these or a fast alternative in a program?

Thanks,

Mark Ch.

Answer (score 1):

It's defined in this [Cython source file](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/cwitty/sage/devel/sage-main/sage/gsl/probability_distribution.pyx) (for module `probability_distribution`) as being mediated by the method `cum_distribution_function_inv` of an instance of class `RealDistribution` when its `self.distribution_type==beta`.  So you should import the module, instantiate the class, and then call the method -- e.g.

```
from gsl import probability_distribution
thebeta = probability_distribution.RealDistribution(type='beta',
                                                    parameters=[alpha, beta])
print thebeta.cum_distribution_function_inv(0.1)
```

I don't have a GSL installation at hand to test this code (so there might be some minor detail wrong here!) but I do hope this points you in the right direction.